# Words or phrases for someone that is ready to escape quickly, usually due to danger

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I'm looking for a word or short phrase that describes a situation in which there is danger and you should be ready to move / escape quickly.

The only thing that comes to mind is "Pack Light" or "Sleep Light", but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: Does "on the qui vive" or any of its synonyms work for you? https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/on%20the%20qui%20vive

Comment: OP you need to provide more context. Also, please provide a sentence in which you want to use this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "vigilant"?

> alertly watchful especially to avoid danger

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vigilant

Comment: Vigilant is all-observant like a watchman. Like an Argus monster, who served as watchman at the time of war. From that we get **Argus-eyed.** Argus-eyed is synonymous to vigilant. I think, OP is looking for a term that describes a person who is wary of the situation and always ready to escape from the place (of hiding). Like a spy in an other country.

Answer (score 1):

An expression for this is to **sleep with one eye open**:

From [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+with+one+eye+open):

> To stay awake or sleep very lightly so as to remain very wary, cautious, or alert. *I won't forget this insult. You'd better start sleeping with one eye open, because I'll get my revenge.*

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sleep_with_one_eye_open):

> Sleep very lightly, aware of what is happening around one.
>
> ‘the woman was like a cat sleeping with one eye open, watching everything that went on’
> ‘She must have heard something because according to her father she slept with one eye open at all times.’
> ‘I have spent my life in an area where you needed to sleep with one eye open to survive.’